# Dimming all the views in the background of a button

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton

I have a menu button (+) at the top right of a view, when then button is pressed several other buttons drop down for the user to select.

I would like to dim all the views below all these buttons efficiently.

The way I am currently doing it is by having a transparent view on top of everything and changing the background colour as well as its transparency after the button is clicked.

```
if button.isHidden {
    self.dimView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    self.dimView!.alpha = 0.7
} else {
    self.dimView!.alpha = 0
}
```

Is this method of achieving this efficient? Efficient in the sense that it wont interfere with touches and wont slow down the phone?

Comment: if this view is in the background, then it wouldn't interfere with the touches of drop down buttons.

Comment: @ShamasS the view is on top of tableviews and other labels in the background, it doesn't seem to interfere with touches even though its on top of those views but I am not sure if it will cause the tableview to lag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dimming view **should** disable taps on the views it covers when it's alpha is above 0.5.

If you set the alpha to 0, you should probably set `view.hidden=true`. That way the rendering system isn't trying to composite it with the other views on-screen. (Set `hidden=false` before setting the alpha to 0.7, and `hidden=true` in addition to/instead of setting the alpha to 0. Unless you're animating the alpha change, with hidden=true, the alpha value is irrelevant.)

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for, but just to be clear, is this the best way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure about the **best** way, but it's what I've done, and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Well the transparent view should be in background of all the subviews of your ViewController, to achieve the desired  result.

Regarding the efficient and  optimised way, then  it will be better to set the opaque property of view, here is the description :-

> "Opaque" property provides a hint to the drawing system as to how it
>   should treat the view. If set to true, the drawing system treats the
>   view as fully opaque, which allows the drawing system to optimize some
>   drawing operations and improve performance. If set to false, the
>   drawing system composites the view normally with other content. The
>   default value of this property is true.
>
> An opaque view is expected to fill its bounds with entirely opaque
>   content—that is, the content should have an alpha value of 1.0. If the
>   view is opaque and either does not fill its bounds or contains wholly
>   or partially transparent content, the results are unpredictable. You
>   should always set the value of this property to false if the view is
>   fully or partially transparent.

The code should be like this:-

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.75)
view.isOpaque = false
```

Comment: Sorry I think my question isn't very clear, I added a regular view on top of all my labels and buttons but below my (+) button. When I click this Button I turn the view I placed on top of those other views black and make it transparent.